# On the observability of nonlinear systems

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system

I am looking for a reference on the observability of nonlinear systems of the form $$\begin{aligned} \dot{x} &= f(x,u) \\ y &= h(x) \end{aligned}$$ As far as I remember, it should be something dual to the controllability/feedback linearization via the Lie derivatives. Unfortunately, years have passed since I touched the subject last time and, surprisingly, I cannot find anything related in my notes. I am looking, e.g., for a tutorial or lecture notes that can be given to (good) students.

Comment: There is a review with a bibliography of 176 items: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10513-005-0147-5

Comment: I think every engineering book on control theory has a chapter on Observability/Controllability. 
E.g. here http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @don'tstopthebit I see only linear systems there. Not the same

Comment: Have you checked the book by Sontag or the one by Sastry?

Comment: I assume there should be something on observability on Isidori's *Nonlinear Control Systems*. If not, perhaps on Jurdjevic's *Geometric Control Theory*?